# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2+x^2 \csc ^2 x}{\sin ^2 x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int \frac{(x^2+x^2 \csc ^2 x) \:dx}{\sin ^2 x}$$

My try:

we have $$I=\int x^2 \csc ^2 x\,dx+\int x^2 \csc ^4 x\,dx=P+Q$$

where $$P=\int x^2 \csc ^2 x\,dx$$ and $$Q=\int x^2 \csc ^4 x\,dx=\int x^2 \csc^2 x \times \csc ^2 x\,dx$$

Using Parts for $P$ we get

$$P=x^2 (-\cot x)+\int 2x \cot x\,dx \tag{1}$$

Using Parts for $Q$ we get

$$Q=x^2 \csc ^2 x(-\cot x)+\int \left(-2x^2 \csc^2 x\cot x+2x\csc ^2 x\right)\cot x\,dx$$ $\implies$

$$Q=x^2 \csc ^2 x(-\cot x)+\int \left(-2x^2 \csc^2 x\cot^2 x\right)dx+\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx$$ $\implies$

$$Q=x^2 \csc ^2 x(-\cot x)+\int \left(-2x^2 \csc^4 x\right)dx+\int 2x^2 \csc^2 x\,dx+\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx$$ $\implies$

$$3Q=x^2 \csc ^2 x(-\cot x)+2P+\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx \tag{2}$$ Now

$$\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx=2x \cot x(-\cot x)+\int \left (-x \csc^2 x+\cot x \right)\cot x\,dx$$

$\implies$

$$\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx=\frac{2x \cot x(-\cot x)+\int \left (\cot x \right)\cot x\,dx}{3}$$

$\implies$

$$\int 2x \csc^2 x\cot x\,dx=\frac{2x \cot x(-\cot x)-\cot x-x}{3}$$

$$3Q-2P=x^2 \csc ^2 x(-\cot x)+\frac{2x \cot x(-\cot x)-\cot x-x}{3}$$

But with this can we find $P+Q$?

Comment: Do you want that one checks your derivations?

Comment: If you want to make sure your answer is correct, you can just go to wolframalpha.com.

Comment: No i want to actually find $P+Q$ but i got $3Q-2P$

Comment: Sorry...  It was a long, not-to-easy-to-read post, I didn't fully realize what you got and what you didn't.

Comment: I checked with WolframAlpha, and want to warn you that the result involves a function like the polylogarithmic function $\text{Li}_2$.  And frankly, it is very nasty.

Comment: You have expressed $P$ in terms of elementary functions plus  $\int x \cot(x) dx$. So you can plug that in to the last equation and get $Q$ in the same form and then $P+Q$ in the same form. If you want to go further, then as @Batominovski notes, the integral involves $Li_2$. Is that what you are looking for?